# Rename the key field to id (NzTreeNodeOptions)

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

Good afternoon.
I use ng-zorro Tree.

By default, the NzTreeNodeOptions interface has a **key** field, my structure only contains the **id** field, how can I change the name of the **key** field to **id**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was thinked only this:

```
      addKeyField(item: ProductsInterface[]): ProductsInterface[]{

   return  item.map((el: ProductsInterface) => {
       // return (el.children) ? this.addKeyField(el.children) : ({...item, key: el.id});
        if(el.children){
            return ({...el, children: this.addKeyField(el.children), key: el.id})
            //this.addKeyField(el.children);
        }   
        
        return ({...el, key: el.id})
    })

 // return t;
  }
```

It is good, only async data some tree nodes.